# Are code contracts for vs 2015 stable now?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-contracts

I'm thinking about adding Code Contracts to our project. We use C# and Visual Studio 2015. I have read that Code Contracts were broken for this version because of new Roslyn Compiler. Is it still true?

Also if it turns out that I will be the only person in the team who uses code contracts is it necessary for others to install code contracts on their machines?

I want to be sure that my commit won't break the build if my team decides to not use the contracts.

Comment: It works, but has bugs. This should give you an overview: https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I leave contracts in code that I'm merging with a codebase used by non-code contracts developers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627419/can-i-leave-contracts-in-code-that-im-merging-with-a-codebase-used-by-non-code)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks, that link is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Code Contracts project is abandoned. There is no re-writer for .net core/.net 5 and the project lead switched from Microsoft Research to Facebook.
Here are some other related SO questions with links:

[Are code contracts supported in .net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64985444/are-code-contracts-supported-in-net-core)

[What happened to Code Contracts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876105/what-happened-to-code-contracts)