# Are code contracts supported in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, code-contracts

In the .net framework there were Code Contracts which allowed me to specify pre/post conditons in my code. Are they supported in .net core/.net 5?

Comment: yes, if you click on `System.Diagnostics.Contracts` it is version net 5 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts

Comment: Great, thanks. If you can format this as an answer I will accept it

Comment: hm, namespace is available but I found this interesting thread  https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23869

Comment: Well that's a pity. So they keep the namespace but are missing a rewriter. And it is unclear if they will support it in the future. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Namespace `System.Diagnostics.Contracts` is available but project is **abandoned**.

Alternative VS2019
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47108/the-best-code-contracts-alternative-for-vs-2017-2019-and-net-core-projects

Discussion about .Net Core

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23869

Is Code Contracts still the recommended way to go in 2020

https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/17640

Comment: It seems this link from the comment to stack exchange question is the most informative:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23869#issuecomment-415670905
Seems like the project lead switched to Facebook and the project was abandoned.